# Multiple labels in supervised learning algorithm

Tags: text-mining, supervised-learning

I have a corpus of text with a corresponding topics. For example `"A rapper Tupac was shot in LA"` and it was labelled as `["celebrity", "murder"]`. So basically each vector of features can have many labels (not the same amount. The first feature vector can have 3 labels, second 1, third 5).

If I would have just one label corresponded to each text, I would try a [Naive Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), but I do not really know how should I proceed if I can have many labels.

Is there any way to transform Naive Bayes into multi label classification problem (if there is a better approach - please let me know)?

**P.S.** few things about the data I have.

- approximately 10.000 elements in the dataset
- text is approximately 2-3 sentences
- maximum 7 labels per text

Comment: What does it mean for a feature vector to have -1 labels?

Comment: @goangit sorry, I meant 1 label.

Comment: How is the distribution of your labels. Any classes with few positives?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a procedure which does the following:

> ```
> For each unique label:
>  Define positives as texts containing labels
>  Define negatives as text not containing the label
>  Balance negatives and positives by oversampling the minority class
>  Train SVM or Naive Bayes model on trainingset
> End:
> ```

You probably also want a test set which you need to extract before running this procedure.

There is a lot of literature on multiclass problems, but I dont think your problem is a traditional multiclass problem.